# Custom collection flow layout for UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

i'm learning iOS with Swift, and now i wanted to create simple messenger app (very very simple version of WhatsApp). I've looked through all collection view video tutorials, but i still cannot understand how to create a layout, where cells will be on two sides of the screen (two cells couldn't be in one row). 
So as far as i understand, i should go with flow layout. I override layoutAttributesForElementsInRect like this:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
    for attribute in attributes {
        attribute.frame.origin.x = collectionView!.bounds.width - attribute.frame.width
    }
    return attributes
}
```

And now my cells lay under each other (for example i have 50 cells, but i could see only 10 with 5 cells in depth).

EDIT: As you can see, 5 cells lay under each other in each row, so totally i got 10 rows, not 50.

[image][image]

And i want to see all 50 cells from right side.

So could somebody give any advice how can i implement this layout. 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's hard to understand from your description what you want to see and what you do see. Could you please update your question with screenshots / illustrations to help explain?

Comment: I don't see where you're changing the cell origins'  `y` values.

Comment: Is this only way to move cells under each other? Shouldn't collection view automatically place cells under each other with equal spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit late, but hopefully useful.

1) If you want to display one column of cells, why not go with a UITableView?

2) Make two cells, one 'me' cell and one 'other person' cell. They look different: Different colors perhaps but the one cell has the Labels aligned to the Left, the other to the right. When using a UICollectionView, the cells should be wider than Half the screen, so that they are automagically placed in one column. No need to override layoutAttributesForElementsInRect in a custom FlowLayout subclass.